# Write database table to array / hash table

Tags: php

I have an array with data from a database, it is built like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ColumnName01] => Toplevel some value
            [ColumnName02] => Sublevel some value
            [ColumnName03] => some value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ColumnName01] => Toplevel some value
            [ColumnName02] => Sublevel some value
            [ColumnName03] => another value
        )
    ...
```

So now I want this stuff into a new array (or hashtable), that looks like this:

```
Array 
(
    [Toplevel some value] => Array
        (
            [Sublevel some value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => some value
                    [1] => another value
                )
        )
    [Toplevel some value] => Array
        (
            [Sublevel another value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => some value 2
                    [1] => another value 2
                )
        )
)
```

(Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do).

And I'm wondering how to do this in PHP?!

Answer (score 2):

You can perform this:

```
$result = array();
// $array is source array
foreach($array as $value) {
    $top = array_values(array_shift($value));
    $sub = array_values(array_shift($value));
    $result[$top[0]][$sub[0]] = array_values($value);
}

//here you result
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Almost, but I have several $value for $sub, and several $sub for $top. In your solution I only get one value for one sub.